# colouring a multilayer plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recreate the following plot as a `ggplot2` multilayered object but I think I'm having a harder time than what I thought.
[image]

Right now I've been able to sketch out the general idea as a stack of three layers:

- `geom_rect` for vertical colours
- `geom_rect` for horizontal striped/dotted patterns
  (- `geom_point` for what will be plotted on that)

but some big issues appeared:

1. `ggplot2` seems not to interpret my colours stored in a dataframe (neither as names [e.g. 'red'] nor as hexadecimals values). I tried to provide them as a named vector (see first solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279570/assign-point-color-depending-on-data-frame-column-value-r)) but with no luck.
   [image]
2. I tried `ggpattern` but it applies the same pattern across the whole chart space
3. being transparent, I tried "00" as a hexadecimal value for the lower `geom_rect`, but had the same outcome of issue n.1
4. `geom_point` does not recognise the field 'wtype' returning `object not found`

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve them after quite a bit of reading&testing at least half of StackOverflow.

I know it's a complex question but looked weird to open 3 different questions for what -to me- relates to a general problem of properly managing multiple layers.

Here the code and some data:

```
vparam.df = data.frame(
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 15,
  xmin = c(0, 7, 14, 21, 28),
  xmax = c(7, 14, 21, 28, 35)
  , xlabel = c(3.5, 10.5, 17.5, 24.5, 31.5)
  , ylabel = rep(-1,5)
  , fill = c("#1e8449", "#52be80", "#f4d03f", "#f39c12","#c0392b")
  #, fill = c("red", "orange","yellow","lightgreen","darkgreen")
  , label = c("low","mod. low","medium","pretty strong","strong")
)

hparam.df = data.frame(
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 35,
  ymin = c(5, 10),
  ymax = c(10, 15)
  , xlabel = rep(-1, 2)
  , ylabel = c(7.5, 12.5)
  #, fill = c("dots", "diagonals") # THIS IS HOW I IMAGINE IT
  , fill = c( "#52be80", "#c0392b")
  , label = c("medium","strong")
)

df = structure(list(xvar = c(13, 20, 16, 11, 21, 13, 13, 7, 9, 16, 
11, 13, 15, 13, 22, 16), yvar = c(0, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 7, 5, 5, 
0, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2, 7), wtype = c("Type4", "Type3", 
"Type4", "Type4", "Type1", "Type1", 
"Type4", "Type1", "Type1", "Type1", 
"Type3", "Type1", "Type2", "Type4", 
"Type2", "Type1")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



ggplot(df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar )) +
  geom_rect(
    data = vparam.df,
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +

  geom_rect(
    data = hparam.df,
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill), alpha = .2,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  
  geom_point( size=1 ) +

  geom_text(data=vparam.df, aes(x=xlabel, y=ylabel, label=label), size=2) +
  geom_text(data=hparam.df, aes(x=xlabel, y=ylabel, label=label), size=2,angle=90) +
  scale_y_discrete( limits=seq(0,15,5) ) +
  scale_x_discrete( limits=seq(0,35,7) ) +
  theme( legend.position="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scale_fill_identity` and `scale_pattern_identity` to make your life easier here. Rather than using your data, I have reproduced the plot from scratch here - the following is a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

data.frame(xmin = c(0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 0, 0),
           xmax = c(7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 35, 35),
           ymin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10),
           ymax = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 15),
           pat  = c('none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'circle', 'stripe'),
           fill = c('#fe0003', '#ff8347', '#ffff01', '#02ff07', '#008203',
                    '#00000000', '#00000000')) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_rect_pattern(aes(xmin = xmin, ymin = ymin, xmax = xmax, ymax = ymax,
                        fill = fill, pattern = pat), pattern_fill = 'black') +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(x = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, rep(-0.1, 3)),
                                   y = c(rep(-0.1, 5), 1/6, 3/6, 5/6),
                                   gp = grid::gpar(col = 'gray', fontface = 4),
                                   label = c('basso', 'abbastanza\nbasso',
                                             'medio', 'abbastanza\nmedio',
                                             'forte', 'basso', 'medio', 'forte'))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, color = wtype), size = 4, data = df) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_pattern_identity() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Type1 = 'white', Type2 = 'black',
                                Type3 = 'gray', Type4 = 'violet')) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:5 * 7, 
                     labels = ~ ifelse(.x == 0, 0,
                                       paste0(.x, ' (', scales::percent(.x/35), ')'))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3 * 5, 
                     labels = ~ paste0(.x, ' (', scales::percent(.x/15), ')')) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, clip = 'off') +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = 'black'),
        plot.margin = margin(10, 30, 30, 30),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: that's...astonshing! may I ask you to integrate explaining 1) why in my example colours are not interpreted correctly and 2) how to add the "third layer" plotting df as white dots or coloured by group, please? I just tried adding geom_point(data=df, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, colour=wtype) but still colour is not the desired one

Comment: Your colors are not interpreted correctly because at no point do you tell ggplot that the variable you have mapped to `fill` is _supposed_ to be interpreted as colours. That's exactly what `scale_fill_identity` does. Otherwise, ggplot assumes the column is a character variable that is supposed to be assigned a color from its standard palette.

Comment: Your `geom_point` call is correct, but to control the colors, you need to specify a color scale - see my update showing how to do this with `scale_color_manual` @Nico